# How to remove currency metadata from salesforce reports

Tags: metadata-api

Im trying to remove currency metadata from reports permanently  .
The intention of removing the metadata was to default display the currency in reports and dashboard according to User Currency setting(local currency) 
Using MavensMate I was able to remove it and able to fullfill the task,but what is happening is if any change made in currency from reports EDIT> CUSTOMIZE>SHOW > CURRENCY OPTION.
Default it saves the currency tag in meta data and any further change made to the currency from user its not replicating to the reports as required but shows the currency which has been saved in metadata.
Is there any way to stop the metadata which has been removed being saved and permanently show the currency according to the user local currency setting ?